# Resource association with class error

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I used editor in VS2008 to create some dialogs. Then I clicked with right button to add class through wizard. Everything worked and I did some coding. After some added members and code I wanted to add click button handler through editor. But it offered me only new class dialog wizard. Dialog appears as it has no class attached in editor.
Application runs fine and I am able to build it.
This is not the first time I had similar problem with editor. I deleted .ncb, .suo, all build files, .aps file but nothing works to make editor detect appropriate class for dialog. What could be causing this?

Comment: In VS2008 the link between a dialog class and its resource is made via the `enum { IDD = IDD_YOURDIALOG }` entry in the class header. If you removed or changed it, it will break that link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatelly I didn't mess with this. Enum is still there unmodified. Otherwise I doubt application would run correctly and would not be able to use correct dialog resource. Problem is present only in editor.

Comment: This would be a good time to understand the Wizard-generated code. Use the [`ON_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5f1bcxd.aspx) macro to add an event handler to your [Message Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1.aspx).

Comment: Problem is not in that I would not know it, but in that it is slowing me down.